# C# Load scaled bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

Im trying to load a n by n image and make in n*m by n*m by duplicating each pixel to be m x m. What i mean: if the image was:

```
1 2

3 4
```

and m is 2 so the new image will be

```
1 1 2 2

1 1 2 2

3 3 4 4

3 3 4 4
```

So far i just done the obvious way:

```
Bitmap scaledImage = new Bitmap(image.Width * BeadWidth, image.Height * BeadHeight);
  for (int w = 0; w < scaledImage.Width; ++w) {
      for (int h = 0; h < scaledImage.Height; ++h) {
          scaledImage.SetPixel(w, h, image.GetPixel(w / BeadWidth, h / BeadHeight));
     }
  }
```

but it take such a long time.
How can i get the same result in a much faster time?

Comment: 1. Don't do scaling yourself, use `graphics.DrawImage` to scale images for you, you can explicitly request nearest-neighbour interpolation.

Comment: 2. Don't use `GetPixel` and `SetPixel`, they're slow. Instead, manipulate `Bitmap` objects by using `LockBits` and either copying the data to a `Byte[]` array (for safety) or use `unsafe` C# with pointers to quickly iterate -over and manipulate bitmap data without copying.

Answer (score 2):

[DrawImage(Image, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbsak4dc(v=vs.110).aspx)
Draws the specified Image at the specified location and with the specified size.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width*2, height*2);
Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
graph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
graph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graph.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width*2, height*2));
```

> While this will be high quality, I don't think he actually wants
>   anti-aliased, interpolating results. If that is so, the correct
>   settings would be:

```
graph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor; 
graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```

Comment: While this will be high quality, I don't think he actually wants anti-aliased, interpolating results. If that is so, the correct settings would be: `graph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by simply using the following [Bitmap Constructor (Image, Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/334ey5b7(v=vs.110).aspx) overload like this

```
var scaledImage = new Bitmap(image, image.Width * BeadWidth, image.Height * BeadHeight);
```